# Change the style of chapter in LyX

Tags: formatting, lyx, chapters

I'm trying to change the style of chapter using LyX 2.1.0.
Like this style (I have the code TeX but I failed to execute):

[image]

The class of my document is `report`.

[image]

here is the code for the chapter tikz

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}

  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}

      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
Text
\chapter{Main}

\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that fails to execute?

Comment: I edited my publication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the two empty lines in the definition of `\titleformat`, and your code works fine. So, what you need to add to the LaTeX preamble in the document settings in LyX is the code given below. In addition you should add `svgnames` to the Custom class options in Document --> Settings --> Document class:

[image]

Note also that the chapter headings require at least two compilation runs because of `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]`, and LyX does not do this automatically I think. However, if you have anything else in your document requiring several compilation runs, such as a cross reference, it should work fine.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got these errors : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/816427err.png

Comment: @user1936895 Add `svgnames` to the class options. I edited my answer.

Comment: I could not add "svgnames", since the field is disabled :http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/188452err1.png

Comment: @user1936895 Not that one, the one below (Réglable).

Comment: I encountered this error : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/185591err2.png

Comment: @user1936895 You can try doing what the error says, and add `full` to the class options. Or you can try changing `\usepackage{kpfonts}` to `\usepackage[notextcomp]{kpfonts}`.

Comment: I Changed the package, its works, thank you so much